# Warning: Missing 1 argument

Tags: php, constructor, warnings

Any idea why I get this error:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for person::__construct(), called in /home/fishbein/public_html/dev/OOP/index.php on line 5 and defined in /home/fishbein/public_html/dev/OOP/class_lib.php on line 6

Warning: Missing argument 1 for person::__construct(), called in /home/fishbein/public_html/dev/OOP/index.php on line 6 and defined in /home/fishbein/public_html/dev/OOP/class_lib.php on line 6
```

With this code:

```
<?
    class person {

            var $name;

            function __construct($persons_name) {       
            $this->name = $persons_name;        
            }

            function set_name($new_name) {
                $this->name = $new_name;
            }

            function get_name() {
                return $this->name;
            }

    }
?>
```

I'm also using this in my index file:

```
$tyler = new person("Tyler");
```

Comment: You need to publish lines 5 and 6 on index.php. That's where the bug is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When instantiated you did: `$obj = new person();` instead of `$obj = new person("joe");`

Comment: But, I'm using $tyler = new person("Tyler");

Comment: $tyler = new person; $tyler::set_name("Tyler"); ... remove construct and try like this.

Comment: In your class do  function __construct($persons_name="").

Answer (score 4):

```
$persons_name = ""
```

Set it like this in argument. But that is not solution. You can remove construct, make new instance and then set name. If yours somehow doesn't work.

Comment: +1 for explaining __construct(). __construct( $persons_name = "" ) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the constructor without passing in an argument. Perhaps you are doing something like
`$p = new person();` instead of `$p = new person("theirName");`

Comment: @Phil: It's at the end of Brian's answer: `$p = new Person("theirName");`

Comment: I've been doing this: $tyler = new person("Tyler");

Answer (score 0):

It seems: 
If the class name is the same as the function name this warning is given. 
If you name the function differently from class name it seems OK. 
You need to supply arguments only when calling he function not at the class instantiation

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 function __construct($persons_name= NULL) {       
            $this->name = $persons_name;        
            }
```

initialized NULL inside construct method.